# Debugging "Invalid return type" in generated code?

Tags: magento2, debugging, code-generation

Is there a way to track down this error report?

```
stdClass Object
(
    [0] => Invalid return type
    [1] => #0 /home/maxxcou1/public_html/mag2/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#1 /home/maxxcou1/public_html/mag2/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(256): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch()
#2 /home/maxxcou1/public_html/mag2/index.php(42): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))
#3 {main}
    [url] => /mag2/admin/amasty_paction/massaction/index/key/2f2b5793ff8167eb1d271f50b9837540854828b56d8a0e963069d44d700586af/
    [script_name] => /mag2/index.php
)
```

This occurs if I replace categories with Amasty extension, **but** it seems the problem is somewhere else. Tested extension on nearly plain magento and it works ...

Any ideas how to find the method, that causes `Invalid return type`?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that some other extension have overwritten the same functionality which Amasty is accepting from default Magento. And the Return type from that extension is not correct may be array and json is expected or vice versa.

One way to debug is to uninstall the extension one by one and see which extension overrides the admin massaction save.

Another way to debug is to use breakpoints using xdebug on phpstorm, or sublime. And see which method is being called when the action is triggered and what it returns.

Second thing can be just try to clear generated/code folder and see if it works. Just a thought may be that can be an issue.